# Python: Efficient unrolling/flattening list of tuples and single floats

Tags: python, list, tuples, flatten

I have a list of tuples and single floats

```
v = [(1., 2., 3.), (4., 5.), 6., 7.]
```

Now I want to flatten it with the good old list comprehension

```
[item for sublist in v for item in sublist]
```

But an error occurs as single floats are not iterable. What is the most efficient way to unroll this mixed list? I tried to go through the list and use `isininstance()` but once again, the list is not iterable.

EDIT: time comparisons so far

- numpy approach with hstack: 6.49 µs ± 100 ns per loop
- hasattr approach: 398 ns ± 2.11 ns per loop
- collections approach: 804 ns ± 1.27 ns per loop

Comment: And that's why building such inconsistent-type lists in the first place is a bad idea.

Comment: @Kelly that's a common issue in [tag:pandas], many use lists, nested lists, json, dictionaries… as items and then are surprised that using the data is slow ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`hasattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr) to check if the object is iterable (has a `__iter__` method):

```py
out = [item for sublist in v
       for item in (sublist if hasattr(sublist, '__iter__') else [sublist])]
```

output: `[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0]`

An alternative would be to use [`collections.abc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html):

```py
from collections.abc import Iterable
    
out = [item for sublist in v
       for item in (sublist if isinstance(sublist, Iterable) else [sublist])]
```

*Note that in both cases, strings are considered iterable, you might want to check for this specific case depending on your data.*

Comment: @Mime if you only have floats, of course, but what about integers, None, of any non-iterable object? I tried to provide a generic answer. But that's a very good point if you have a specific use-case ;)

Comment: For a generice answer it's really better to use `collections.abc`, to much trying to not use any dependency on my side.

Comment: @Alex for a more robust comparison of the different approaches (with varying lengths):  https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZmte.png It seems independent of the size (not surprising)

Answer (score 2):

With `numpy` you can use [hstack()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html):

```
v = [(1., 2., 3.), (4., 5.), 6., 7.]
v = np.hstack(v)

# Output
array([1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7.])
```

Answer (score 0):

The [more-itertools](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) package has a function specifically for this problem -

```py
from more_itertools import collapse
v = [(1., 2., 3.), (4., 5.), 6., 7.]
print(list(collapse(v))
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0]
```

It works with strings too -

```py
x = [('ab', 'cd'), 'e', ['f', 'gh']]
print(list(collapse(x))
['ab', 'cd', 'e', 'f', 'gh']
```